# void with scanf function in C

Tags: c

how can i access inputs from the keyboard through scanf() function which resides inside a function with a return value of void ?Here is the function void read(void);

```
void read(void) {
    int index;
    int sum;
    for (index = 0; index < MAX; index ++)
    {
        printf ("\n Enter the first element with the index %d: ",index);
        scanf ("%d",&a[MAX] );
    }
}
```

here **a** is a global array ( int a[MAX];) and MAx is preprocessor directive with the value of 10 (#define MAX 10)i want to access the array value to the another function to calculate the average of the entered numbers. 
Thank you so much in advance.

Comment: maybe `scanf ("%d",&a[MAX] );` --> `scanf("%d", &a[index] );`

Comment: why the void constraint??

Comment: You probably want to avoid the name `read` for your function, there exists a function by that name in the standard library. You might encounter unexpected link issues otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

`scanf ("%d", &a[index]);` instead of `scanf ("%d", &a[MAX]);`

```
void read(void){
    int index;
    int sum;
    for (index = 0; index < MAX; index ++)
    {
        printf ("\n Enter the first element with the index %d: ",index);
        scanf ("%d", &a[index]);
    }
    a[0]; // first integer input
    a[1];
    a[2];
    a[3];
    a[4];
    a[5];
    ...

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have trying to scan the value of array out of bound.So, result is **undefined behaviour** because array index start from 0.

So, use this:

```
scanf ("%d",&a[index] );
```

Instead of

```
scanf ("%d",&a[MAX] );
```